# How to hide grid lines in graphs in React chart js 2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am using react-chartjs-2 version 5 and I want to hide the gridlines. I have tried this code snippet but did not work.

```
xAxes: [
    {
      display: false,
      gridLines: {
        display: false,
        zeroLineColor: "transparent"
      }
    }
  ],
  yAxes: [
    {
      display: false,
      gridLines: {
        display: false,
        zeroLineColor: "transparent"
      },
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I think what you have under `xAxes: [{...}]` and `yAxes:[{....}]` should be under `scales:{x:{...}, y:{...}}` (no arrays), assuming everything is in `options`. Please provide a full running [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or at least the whole configuration to make things easier for us.

Answer (score 1):

I run it on "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0", on React TS project:
Just add In option for your chart grid display:false

```
const options = {
    scales: {
        y: {
            grid: {
                display: false
            }
        },
        x: {
            grid: {
                display: false
            }
        },
    }
}
    
<Line options={options} data={data}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried your snippet but its not working in `react-chartjs-2` v5.2

Solution: you can simply raplace `xAxes, yAxes` with `x,y` and instead of `gridLines` with `grid` inside `scales`

```
scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    y: {
      grid: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
```

I removed gridlines here: [removed gridlines here](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-dream-m4ife6?file=/App.tsx)